# Table horizontal scroll without modifying outer wrappers

Tags: html, css, html-table

I have a table, and I'd like to add horizontal scroll on it.

However I cannot change the outer wrapper (.app) and the body values.

I've tried a couple of things like overflow-x: scroll; and white-space: nowrap; with no luck mostly I've ended with a scroll bar without scrolling...

I've made a codesandbox to experiment with... still no clue how should solve it with this "restrictions": https://codesandbox.io/s/keen-boyd-8cgw0w?file=/src/styles.css

```
body {
  overflow: hidden;
}

.outer-wrap {
  background-color: red;
  width: 100vh;
  height: 50vh;
}

/* Can't modifiy body, or the .outer-wrap */

.wrap {
  background-color: green;
  padding: 1rem;
  /* can't modifiy this width! */
  width: 100%;
  overflow-x: scroll;
}

table {
  overflow-x: scroll;
}

th,
tr,
td {
  /* it just to make the table wide */
  padding-left: 10rem;
}
```

And my html looks like this:

```
<div class="outer-wrap">
      <div class="wrap">
        <table>
          <tbody>
            <tr>
              <th>1</th>
              <th>2</th>
              <th>3</th>
              <th>4</th>
              <th>5</th>
              <th>6</th>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>A</td>
              <td>B</td>
              <td>C</td>
              <td>D</td>
              <td>E</td>
              <td>F</td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: `width: 100vh;` should be `width: 100vw;` for `.outer-wrap`. I think the `vh` value is not supported for the width property. Also add `overflow-x: auto;` for the same

Comment: vh was a typo from my part, that's vw obviously. Actually I've got the solution, needed a plus wrapper with a width calc(100vw - somthing)  ... thanks

Answer (score 0):

here is the front end of trust ready to answer, first of all do not use vh to define the width because you do not want that when you make the resize of the screen vertically containers are resized horizontally, almost always for heights are used fixed or automatic sizes, regarding your problem instead you should set overflow-x: auto to the red container and put as width for the green container width:fit-content.

I hope I was helpful

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).